# Create conditional column for Date Difference based on matching values in two columns

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, numpy, data-science

I have a dataframe, I am struggling to create a column based out of other columns, I will share the problem for a sample data.

```
        Date    Target1        Close
0   2019-04-17  209.2440    203.130005
1   2019-04-17  212.2155    203.130005
2   2019-04-17  213.6330    203.130005
3   2019-04-17  213.0555    203.130005
4   2019-04-17  212.6250    203.130005
5   2019-04-17  212.9820    203.130005
6   2019-04-17  213.1395    203.130005
7   2019-04-16  209.2860    199.250000
8   2019-04-16  209.9055    199.250000
9   2019-04-16  210.3045    199.250000
```

I want to create another column (for each observation) (called `days_to_hit_target` for example) which is the difference of days such that close hits (or comes very close to target of specific day), when it does closes that very closely, then it counts the difference of days and put them in the column days_to_hit_target.

Comment: Please post the desired output as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "date for which close and target prices becomes closer". What does **closer** mean here? I do not understand what you want from the example output you present.

Comment: It means, if today close is 203.13, then the day when the target also becomes somewhat equal lets say 203.15 and crosses it, we count the difference of days between first date and the date, when it hot the target.

Comment: I'm still unsure of how you calculate `days_to_hit_target`. Is it some sort of linear regression? Perhaps its best if you provide some example of how you got `53` and `27`

Comment: its just a random number, you will see for equal values of close, they repeats. so, just the date difference when close hits/crosses the same target value.

Comment: @Shivam_hbti Just tag the person in your reply. Please stop writing two replies per answer to comment.

Comment: @SpaceMonkey55 Noted! Did you understand my problem, how can I help more in that case, thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. But your question is poorly worded. I suggest spending some more time in clarifying your question. I am trying to create a solution that suits (*what I interpret of*) your needs.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I am looking over again the question to help understand better.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase your question. You have a target price for each row. You want to know how many days it takes for price to close above said target?

Comment: @micric exactly!

Comment: @micric are you checking it!

Comment: yes, I'll post it soon

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE I use python 3.7.1 and pandas 0.23.4**. I came up with something very dirty; I am sure there is a neater and more efficient way of doing this.

```
### Create sample data
date_range = pd.date_range(start="1/1/2018", end="20/1/2018", freq="6H", closed="right")

target1 = np.random.uniform(10, 30, len(date_range))

close = [[i]*4 for i in np.random.uniform(10,30, len(date_range)//4)]
close_flat = np.array([item for sublist in close for item in sublist])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([np.array(date_range.date), target1,
    close_flat]).transpose(), columns=["date", "target", "close"])


### Create the column you need
# iterating over the days and finding days when the difference between
# "close" of current day and all "target" is lower than 0.25 OR the "target"
# value is greater than "close" value.
thresh = 0.25
date_diff_arr = np.zeros(len(df))
for i in range(0,len(df),4):
    diff_lt_thresh = df[(abs(df.target-df.close.iloc[i]) < thresh) | (df.target > df.close.iloc[i])]
    # only keep the findings from the next day onwards
    diff_lt_thresh = diff_lt_thresh.loc[i+4:]
    if not diff_lt_thresh.empty:
        # find day difference only if something under thresh is found
        days_diff = (diff_lt_thresh.iloc[0].date - df.iloc[i].date).days
    else:
        # otherwise write it as nan
        days_diff = np.nan
    # fill in the np.array which will be used to write to the df
    date_diff_arr[i:i+4] = days_diff

df["date_diff"] = date_diff_arr
```

Sample output:

```
0   2018-01-01    21.64  26.7319        2.0
1   2018-01-01  22.9047  26.7319        2.0
2   2018-01-01  26.0945  26.7319        2.0
3   2018-01-02  10.2155  26.7319        2.0
4   2018-01-02  17.5602  11.0507        1.0
5   2018-01-02  12.0368  11.0507        1.0
6   2018-01-02  19.5923  11.0507        1.0
7   2018-01-03  21.8168  11.0507        1.0
8   2018-01-03  11.5433  16.8862        1.0
9   2018-01-03  27.3739  16.8862        1.0
10  2018-01-03  26.9073  16.8862        1.0
11  2018-01-04  19.6677  16.8862        1.0
12  2018-01-04  25.3599  27.3373        1.0
13  2018-01-04  22.7479  27.3373        1.0
14  2018-01-04  18.7246  27.3373        1.0
15  2018-01-05  25.4122  27.3373        1.0
16  2018-01-05  28.3294  23.8469        1.0
```

Comment: Why have you used it - range(0,len(df),4)

Comment: because i have 4 datapoints per day in my sample data; you have 7 datapoints per day in your sample.

Comment: your output is also not exact differnce of dates, they seem to be 4, 8, 15 or nan, which seems wrong!

Comment: No, this is not fixed, the data points are irregular, can be any, other thing is, did you check your output column.

Comment: **1.** I do not understand what you mean by "not exact difference of dates". How is it wrong? Imagine my `close` value in date 2018-01-01 is `26.19`; And 2 days later one of the four `target` value was `26.41`. The difference between these values is `0.22`. **2.** If **your** data points are irregular, you have to modify the script accordingly. Stackoverflow is not for solving your coding problem. It is for answering questions where you are stuck, **even after you did through research**.

Comment: In my generated output, the date difference was 1 only to match, but your output shows 4, and the other thing, you provide a solution, which is not working, like its not exact differences and what can I do. maybe it is unclear

Comment: **1.** what does "1 only to match mean"? **2** I didn't include any output, what are you talking about "your output". I just included one now. **3** I asked you what you mean by exact differences. Repeating that and asking "what can i do" does not add any value. Either try to explain what you mean by "exact differences" or try to explain why this does not work in better words.

Comment: close price at index 4 is 23.416 crosses the target/hit on index 8, so date difference is 1,, why does it show three.

Comment: **thanks for that clarification.** I will work on a modification. It does that because the script does not look for when the value is exceeded. **I thought** you wanted the date when your value approaches the target. The script (and the accompanying comments) clarify that.

Comment: I am really sorry if I am confusing you.

Comment: I appreciate you still trying. That's whats most important :). I modified my script a little. It *should* now do what you are looking for.

Comment: Still, the last values are not coming up.

Comment: I asked it again, can you please check this question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55966950/date-difference-based-on-matching-values-in-two-columns-pandas

Comment: Why did you create another question for the same thing? You are not supposed to do that. You should edit your question here.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
daysAboveTarget = []
for i in range(len(df.Date)):
    try:
        dayAboveTarget = df.iloc[i:].loc[(df.Close > df.Target1[i])]['Date'].iloc[0]
    except IndexError:
        dayAboveTarget = None
    daysAboveTarget.append(dayAboveTarget)
daysAboveTarget = pd.Series(daysAboveTarget)
df['days_to_hit_target'] = daysAboveTarget - df.Date
```

I sort of overused iloc and loc here, so let me explain.
The variable dayAboveTarget gets the date when the price closes above the target. The first iloc subsets the dataframe to only future dates, the first loc finds the actual results, the second iloc gets only the first result. We need the exception for days where the price never goes above target.

Comment: Your question is tagged Python2, so maybe you will need to change the range function

Comment: It shows me negative days and I think, it is still unclear, I have asked it again, can you please check the link below.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55966950/date-difference-based-on-matching-values-in-two-columns-pandas

Comment: If you sort the df by 'Date', you shouldn't get negative values

Answer (score 0):

maybe a little faster solution:

```
import pandas as pd

# df is your DataFrame
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df = df.sort_values("Date")

def days_to_hit(x, no_hit_default=None):
    return next(
        ((df["Date"].iloc[j+x.name] - x["Date"]).days 
         for j in range(len(df)-x.name) 
         if df["Close"].iloc[j+x.name] >= x["Target1"]), no_hit_default)

df["days_to_hit_target"] = df.apply(days_to_hit, axis=1)
```